# Hide table row(s) in twig with symfony

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, twig

I'm starting coding. I'm using Symfony 3.3
I would like to hide ( and show ) a  or some specifics rows on a table with a checkbox.
I tried with javascript and jquery. I would like that the hidden rows stay hide.
I don't know how to do this. Here is my twig

```
{% block body %}

    <div class="container">
        <h3>List of products</h3>

        <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Charges</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
        <th>Desactivation</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    {% for catalogue in catalogues %}
    <tr class="table">

        <td>{{ catalogue.product}} </td>
        <td>{{ catalogue.description }} </td>
        <td>{{ catalogue.size}} </td>
        <td>{{ catalogue.charge }} </td>
        <td>{{ catalogue.price }}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ path('catalogue_list_edit', { 'id': catalogue.id }) }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
            <a href="{{ path('catalogue_list_delete', { 'id': catalogue.id }) }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
        </td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="boutton35"  value="Desactivation"  />
      </td>

    </tr>

    {% else %}
    {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
        </table>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Sorry I misread . How can you show the hidden row if the checkbox is inside that hidden row

Comment: I think he want to make a 'toggle' with a checkbox and hide some elements. You want to hide an entire row or just some <td> ?

Comment: Until I click again on the checkbox ! 
 
An entire row ! 
 
I think i need the id of all my products ? But I don't know how to recover them . The checkbox could stay ? or i don't know... a button to show all the button hide maybe ?

Comment: Can you walk me through what you are trying to achieve it might be a better way to do it

Comment: The objective is to desactivate a row on my table. I thought about it to hide those rows. But if there is another way, it's ok too

Comment: Like a filter ? or stay deactivated until you want to show it again?

Comment: It should stay desactivated until I want to show it again !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.hideshow').on('click',function(){
  let cls = $(this).attr("data-id")
  if ( $('#'+cls).css('display') == 'none' ){
    $('.table tbody').find('#'+cls).show();
  }else{
    $('.table tbody').find('#'+cls).hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <h3>List of products</h3>

  <div class="buttons">
    <button type="button" data-id="tr1" class="hideshow">Hide/Show Row 1</button>
    <button type="button" data-id="tr2" class="hideshow">Hide/Show Row 2</button>
    <button type="button" data-id="tr3" class="hideshow">Hide/Show Row 3</button>
  </div>
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Charges</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
        <th>Desactivation</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr id="tr1">
        <td>Product </td>
        <td>Description </td>
        <td>Size </td>
        <td>Charges </td>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">Edit</a>
          <a href="#">Remove</a>
        </td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="boutton35" value="Desactivation" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr2">
        <td>Product </td>
        <td>Description </td>
        <td>Size </td>
        <td>Charges </td>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">Edit</a>
          <a href="#">Remove</a>
        </td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="boutton35" value="Desactivation" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr3">
        <td>Product </td>
        <td>Description </td>
        <td>Size </td>
        <td>Charges </td>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">Edit</a>
          <a href="#">Remove</a>
        </td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="boutton35" value="Desactivation" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: That is a good idea. But I will have like 20 rows that are generated throught my database. I don't know how to generate the good id for each

Comment: @Koila69 What do you mean? You have your twig loop right? `{% for catalogue in catalogues %}<button data-id="row-{{ catalogue.id }}">Show/Hide</button>{% endfor %}` and  `{% for catalogue in catalogues %}.... <tr id="row-{{ catalogue.id }}"> ....{% endfor %}`

Comment: @Koila69 If you find this useful you are more than welcome to set it as answer